# corsa 1.2 2007 drain battery

Tags: battery, opel, corsa

I have corsa 1.2 2007 keep losing charge. in the morning start normal. but in the evening not start I try with new battery same things when I plog off the battery wire on the evening car start normal in the morning. I really don't know where the problem

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I noticed a typo on your post. What does "plog" mean? Please edit your post for clarity, and provide any other details you might have which could help us help you!

Comment: Did you add any extra equipment to the car?

Comment: yes I added some internal bulbs

Comment: I mean when I disconnect the battery on the evening and but it back in the morning the car start fine

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a battery drain, but the fact that it starts in the morning is abit strange though, normally battery drain will cause the battery to run flat over a period of time, ie; have to jump start in the mornings, and will be fine driving around through the rest of the day, next morning, same problem. you can check the drain with a multi-meter, switch it to the 10A range, move your one multi-meter cable to the 10A plug on the multi-meter (not the com/comm one, that stays where it is) disconnect the negative terminal at your cars battery and connect one lead from the meter to the negative pole of your battery and the other lead to the negative terminal on the car side battery cable, does not really matter which way around the red and black leads are, reading amount will be the same either way (bare in mind, do this with the ignition off, doors closed and lights etc off, as if you had just parked and closed the car, KEEP KEYS IN YOUR POCKET, or you might end up with the keys locked in the car).

You should get a reading of 0.07A or less, preferably less than 0.05A though, if its higher than 0.07A, check that no lights are on, boot lights can sometime be the culprit, an incorrectly connected radio as well. if you see no obvious items staying on (give it 5mins if you do have a reading over 0.07 to make sure there isnt anything on a time delay) you may want to take it in to a shop to have it checked, trackers are a prime cause of drain and are sometimes hard to find and disconnect or replace the battery, there are multiple other things that could cause it, but its best to let a professional check it